# Should I design in 320px, 375px, or 390px?

Tags: flutter, responsive-design

I'm about to finish the design of my app(Flutterflow). I've been designing everything for 390px. But I remembered that there are still devices that are 320px and 375px. When I set my design to 320px, some things don't look very good. What should I do?

Thank you.